# OffsetDateTime to ZonedDateTime - with specific ZoneId

Tags: java, java-time

We have a DateTime class we created to hold a datetime in our library. The value generally comes from a SQL database (so UTC) or XML (can have an offset). But it can also be a datetime with an explicit timezone (like Denver).

Inside our class we hold this as an OffsetDateTime which I think is best because 98% of the time we're getting an explicit instant with a known offset, and no zone.

When it is initialized with a ZonedDateTime, I'm thinking we save it as an OffsetDateTime and save the ZoneId. Then, only for the case where we want a ZonedDateTime object (converting to a string for display), if we have the ZoneId, apply it to OffsetDateTime.toZonedDateTime(). That way we get  "MST" instead of "-0700" for the 'z' value in displaying as a string.

How can I create a ZonedDateTime with a specific ZoneId from an OffsetDateTime?

Comment: Is [atZoneSimilarLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#atZoneSimilarLocal-java.time.ZoneId-) not what you are looking for?

Comment: A few lines of code will be much more easier instead of this length explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to the specific question you have asked;

```
ZoneId mst = ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));
OffsetDateTime mstOffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(mst);
ZonedDateTime mstZonedDateTime = mstOffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(mst);
```

However, I am not sure why you want to save your timestamp in `OffsetDateTime`. If you keep track of your `ZoneId`, you could save timestamp in UTC and convert to any format as you wish in backend/frontend (or any other client). Storing datetime as UTC would give you more flexibility.

Comment: We're a library and so we have to handle what people using it throw at us. Most set UTC datetimes. But a fair number us datetime set to an offset. And a few set to a zone. We have to handle all cases. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `ZoneId.ofOffset("UTC", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));` Does this mean -7 hours offset from UTC? Official documenation is not very clear. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#ofOffset-java.lang.String-java.time.ZoneOffset-